# insert new row into multi-dimension array php

Tags: php

PHP:

How do you insert a value into specific row in a multi-demension array or insert a empty row in a multi-demension array?

From:

```
a ={ (0,1,2),
     (3,4,5),
     (6,7,8) }
```

to become

```
a ={ (0,1,2),
     (null,null,null),
     (3,4,5),
     (6,7,8) }
```

or null to value i would like to bring in ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this function from [gerry-03 at 4warding dot com](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php#61710) it should be possible:

```
function array_insert(&$input, $offset, $replacement){
    array_splice($input, $offset, 0, 0);
    $input[$offset] = $replacement;
}
```

Demo:

```
$a = array(array(0, 1, 2), array(3, 4, 5), array(6, 7, 8));
array_insert($a, 1, array(9, 10, 11));
```

Result:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [1] => 10
        [2] => 11
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 7
        [2] => 8
    )
```

Comment: Great, could you then [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to mark it as working?